# Find out which scripts create files in the /tmp folder on linux

Tags: linux, logging, tmp

Is it possible to trace which files are creating files in the /tmp folder on a linux OS? I want to back trace some files to find out where they have come from

Comment: In general, the only metadata you have about a file is contained within its [*inode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).  That does not retain any information about the name of the process that created it.

Comment: Names of the files might give you some hints, if they've got something else but what tmpnam() produces.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are open you could find the processes with something like

```
ll -d /proc/[1-9]*/fd/* | grep /tmp/
```